# Having trouble importing < MapView > from 'expo'

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I have been following a tutorial on trying to implement a map onto a mobile application through the use of react native with expo however after running the code i keep receiving multiple error messages which the youtuber giving the tutorial doesnt experience.

**Suspected problem**

The error seems to arise because i am trying to import  from 'expo' but i dont think the expo component exports map view?

**Attempted solution**

npm install expo --save

**Errors Faced**

Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `App`.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { MapView } from 'expo';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = 
    {
      region : 
      {
        latitude: 1.290270,
        longitude: 103.851959,
        latitudeDelta: 0.02,
        longitudeDelta: 0.02,
      }
    }
  }
  render()
  {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>HomeScreen!</Text>
        <MapView 
        initialRegion = {this.state.region}
        showsUserLocation = {true}
        showsCompass = {true}
        rotateEnabled = {false}
        style = {{flex:1}}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to work around a similar problem (on iOS simulator) by running:

`expo install react-native-maps`

and then changing the import to:

`import MapView from "react-native-maps";`

Installation and usage instructions can be found on the Expo documentation page for the MapView component here: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/map-view/